# Has anyone been able to get Xcode 5 to work with MKStoreKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

If so, what changes did you need to make? I can't seen to get in-app purchasing to run with MKStoreKit and Xcode 5.

If I run the same project under Xcode 4, in-app purchases load and work just fine.

Comment: Try on real device. if you are using simulator.